# Fabric JS Curve Text

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have made fabric text curve but its not updating last added text box, if i add new text box then it works but after added another text box then previous text box not working

I have made js Fiddle for the same, check the below link for the same

```
[JSFIDDLE][1]
```

Default added 1 text, click on "Add Text" to add more text, fabric is adding text and works for new text box but not working if you select old text box and want to change the text.

Comment: jsfiddle link not there

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishbhatt/XR7j6/10/

Comment: are you converting the text to another canvas/image and then adding it to base canvas?

Comment: Yes, and because of that its taking full page drawing the canvas, please guide me if you are expert in this as i am new to fabric and needs this feature in my project

Comment: i want to fix fabric control stick to the text and image size and working for multiple text box

Comment: i m sorry i dont understand why you are converting the text to image..
if you have gone through the simple section in http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/
   ,you would be abe to see the same functionality as desired by u

...my advice is to use the text method of fabricjs only..try to follow the method given in the demo only

Comment: I already seen and implemented, but my requirement is to show text in a curve (arc shape), for eg. if i put the text over the bottle product it should like in arc shape or curved shape and it should looks like that its stick to that bottle as per the bottle shape

Comment: ok now i understand.. i wud have dipped in ur code had i not been in the ofc..  may be u will need to replace the instance when user tries to edit it.. or the creator of fabricjs @kangax can help u here :)